# Strange Unity tilemap issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

This issue is a little hard to explain, my first time creating a tilemap in Unity and when I ran the program to test out the camera position on the map, my tilemap converted into [whatever this mess is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xzxg.png) I don't exactly know what happened but I can't seem to revert it back to how it was, if anyone could help me they'd be a total lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the camera size? If the image looks like a low res version of your tilemap than change the size to 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).